# how to create a multiple plain text for subdirectory in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, fedora

this is my whole program but I have no idea how to create a multiple plain text for subdirectory?

```
cd ~
ls -l
mkdir directory 
cd directory 
mkdir sub1
mkdir sub2
mkdir sub3
```

Comment: That is not a program.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are plain text, you can use the touch command with range expansion. So to create 5 test files named from test1.txt to test5.txt, issue the command:

```
touch test{1..5}.txt
```

To create multiple files in all the subdirectories, you can expand the directories as well and so:

```
touch directory/sub{1..3}/test{1..5}.txt
```

Comment: i havent learnd touch yet , but what about ```cat > sub1.text ``` but i want to create a multiple of plain text for each subdirectory

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution to show how to create multiple files in all the subdirectories.